# Montgomery Multiplication - 32-bit register vs. 64-bit register

Tags: math, cryptography, discrete-mathematics, code-complexity, montgomery-multiplication

I need to calculate the speed difference between performing a [Montgomery Multiplication](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf) *page 602-603* with a word-size/register of size 32 vs. 64.

So far, this is what I understand:

- x and y are represented by multiple-word arrays of length n
  where n = m/w and w is the register size (either 32 or
  64).
- The total number of single-digit multiplications in Montgomery
  multiplication is n*(2 + 2*n), where n represents the number length of the word-arrays.
- I will assume that the multiplication of two single-digit takes 1 clock cycle on each of the computers.

How can I put all this together to represent the number of clock cycles needed in Montgomery multiplication on a computer with a 32-bit register or 64-bit register?

Comment: You've already answered your own question: the number of clock cycles is n(2+2*n). It is simple matter to plug in for w=32 and w=64.

Comment: But how do we calculate it since `m` is not known to us? We have `n = m / 32` or 64 respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of cycles for a multiple-precision Montgomery multiplication would indeed be `n(2+2*n)` if all the intermediate single-precision multiplication operands and results were available in registers. For cryptographic operations this is hardly possible since `m` is usually 1024 or larger. Assuming 32-bit registers (x*y*R^-1 mod m) would require 192 registers only to store the operands (3*(1024/32)). In fact you need to take into account memory accesses to answer this question.

A rewrite of the algorithm with memory accesses (assuming multiplications can be done in parallel with loads/stores):

1. For `i` from 0 to n: `a_i <- 0`
2. For `i` from 0 to (n − 1) do the following:

   1. Fetch `a_0`
   2. Fetch `y_0`
   3. Fetch `x_i`
   4. Compute `u_i <- (a_0 + x_i*y_0)m' mod b`. Store `u_i` in a register
   5. `c = 0` (Computing `A <- (A + x_i*y + u_i*m)/b`)
   6. for `j` from 0 to (n-1):

      1. Fetch `a_j`
      2. Fetch `y_j`
      3. Compute `(cv) = a_j + x_i*y_j + c`, Fetch `m_j`
      4. Compute `(cv) = (cv) + u_i*m_j`, if j>0 Store `a_{j-1} <- v`
   7. Store `a_n <- c` and `a_{n-1} <- v`
3. If `A >= m` then `A <- A − m`.
4. Return(A).

Hope this helps.